# How to trigger nightly deployment only when artifacts had changed from last release

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, devops, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In VSTS, I have release definitions with one or more artifacts.

I've scheduled the release to each night automatically:

Release Definition -> Edit -> Pipeline -> Schedule icon in the Artifacts section.

However, sometimes I trigger the release manually or the source code has not changed and therefore there are no new artifacts since last release.

How to avoid releasing the same version multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change your release pipeline like this:

1 - On the pipeline / artifacts, remove your schedule. You will not need it.

[image]

2 - Then on your environment, change the trigger to be after release and enable the schedule, choosing when you want it to start.

[image]

Also in your environment change the deployment queue settings to "deploy latest and cancel others".

3 - Click on your artifact and enable the continuous deployment trigger.

[image]

So every time a build is completed, it will start a release, scheduling it to your defined time. If you build again, the previous release will be canceled to give place to the new one. You maybe can have more releases, but you won't deploy if there were no changes.

Comment: but I have 5 nightly builds that are then combined in the release. Continuous release trigger would not wait until all builds are completed.

Comment: You could trigger the continuous deployment for only one of the artifacts (build). Then on your builds you can add a trigger to builds creating a dependency to start building when another completes, creating a cadence and select the last build on cadence to be the trigger to continuous deploy.